# How does /etc/hosts file affect the connection between datanode and namenode?

Tags: hadoop, ip, hostname

I am now establishing a hadoop cluster(4 machines including 1 master to run namenode and jobTracker, 3 slaves to run dataNode and TaskTraker ).But it is a pitty that all the datanode cannot be connected this master on port 9000.When I use `sudo netsat -ntlp`,result is:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52193           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39267           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7284/rpc.mountd 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33219           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7284/rpc.mountd 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1539/mongos     
tcp6       0      0 :::50030                :::*                    LISTEN      604/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::57134                :::*                    LISTEN      32646/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      13786/rpcbind   
tcp6       0      0 :::57428                :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::57173                :::*                    LISTEN      7284/rpc.mountd 
tcp6       0      0 :::50070                :::*                    LISTEN      32646/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::5910                 :::*                    LISTEN      2452/Xvnc       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      32473/sshd      
tcp6       0      0 :::50744                :::*                    LISTEN      7284/rpc.mountd 
tcp6       0      0 :::55036                :::*                    LISTEN      14031/rpc.statd 
tcp6       0      0 :::42205                :::*                    LISTEN      7284/rpc.mountd 
tcp6       0      0 :::44289                :::*                    LISTEN      504/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::38950                :::*                    LISTEN      604/java        
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9000      :::*                    LISTEN      32646/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9001      :::*                    LISTEN      604/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::50090                :::*                    LISTEN      504/java
```

And my /etc/hosts is:

```
  192.168.10.10   localhost
  192.168.10.10   mongodb
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  #127.0.0.1 localhost
  # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
  ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

mongodb is just the host name.Finally I find out the reason:From the output of netstat,this line:

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9000      :::*                    LISTEN      32646/java
```

We can see that master is only listening on 127.0.0.1:9000,so it cannot receive any connection which is not from 127.0.0.1,thus any datanode cannot connect to it through port 9000.
So ,I changed file /etc/hosts,just switch line 1 and line 2:

```
  192.168.10.10   mongodb
  192.168.10.10   localhost
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  #127.0.0.1 localhost
  # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
  ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And I use `sudo netstat -ntlp` ,the result has changed to

```
tcp6       0      0 192.168.10.10:9000      :::*                    LISTEN      32646/java
```

and of course the datanodes can connect to it through 9000.

**I didn't ever use any hostnames in hadoop configuration files**, all I use is just direct ip address.I know that /etc/hosts/ is used to **map from hostname to ip address** , So ,my question is ,How does /etc/hosts affect the listening ip of hadoop master without using any hostnames?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of speculation here...  Okay, a **lot** of speculation...

First, in parsing /etc/hosts, a mapping of IP to hostnames is created with each entry overwriting any entries that came before.  Thus, in your first configuration, 192.168.10.10 maps to "mongodb" while in the second it maps to "localhost".  A later pass through this "forward" map is used to create a "backward" map and, voila, "localhost" resolves to either 127.0.0.1 or 192.160.10.10 depending on the order of two lines.

Second, your server is binding to "localhost:9000".  Since you didn't specify that in your configuration, it must be in the code.

The easiest thing would be to add to the server configuration so it binds to 0.0.0.0:9000 and thus listens on all interfaces.